Unknown Docker Image RepoDigests
TL;DR: I cannot understand how telegraf@sha256:05cbea951c5cf9da6c663321b32848c1b6ffdfa877563237838efa21b508b079 and telegraf@sha256:848201b0601513122f567a6b690b5ef84abbb38e78ca461d1c1d3d7465691d39 are the same image for telegraf:1.31, whilst the former is mentioned nowhere. I am almost sure these are completely the same images, but I am trying to understand where the unknown sha256:05cbea9 is coming from.
I am working on a host and noticed that the Docker image for Telegraf has two repository digests, which raised some curiosity because I'd expect to see only the index digest or the index digest and the digest for linux/amd64 as the image is multi-architecture image and the host is linux/amd64.
When I run:
docker inspect 4fffb7e682428f97779fdee3f4c44d062de6da9ba4a754a0f3b3f0ecaf87052e on the server, I get the following output:
        "RepoDigests": [
            "telegraf@sha256:05cbea951c5cf9da6c663321b32848c1b6ffdfa877563237838efa21b508b079",
            "telegraf@sha256:6b0d623c54754958fed356d2af239de21dcf7c95d63b76298d0cd70df79cc719"
        ],

The second digest seems fine, as it represents the index digest. However, when I check Docker Hub’s API, the first digest (05cbea...) is not mentioned at all:
curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/library/repositories/telegraf/tags/1.31 | jq '.images[] | "\(.architecture) \(.digest)"' | grep 05cbea951c5cf9da6c663321b32848c1b6ffdfa877563237838efa21b508b079
# Grep returns an empty result here

curl -s https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/library/repositories/telegraf/tags/1.31 | jq '.images[] | "\(.architecture) \(.digest)"' | grep amd64
"amd64 sha256:848201b0601513122f567a6b690b5ef84abbb38e78ca461d1c1d3d7465691d39"

However, they are still the same image. Here's how I checked:
First hash;
docker pull telegraf@sha256:05cbea951c5cf9da6c663321b32848c1b6ffdfa877563237838efa21b508b079

docker images|grep telegraf
telegraf                                                                  <none>      4fffb7e68242   4 weeks ago     472MB

docker inspect 4fffb7e68242 --format='{{json .}}'| jq '"\(.Created) \(.Config.Env[1]) \(.RepoDigests)"'
"2024-08-12T15:27:35Z TELEGRAF_VERSION=1.31.3 [\"telegraf@sha256:05cbea951c5cf9da6c663321b32848c1b6ffdfa877563237838efa21b508b079\"]"

Second hash;
docker pull telegraf@sha256:848201b0601513122f567a6b690b5ef84abbb38e78ca461d1c1d3d7465691d39
docker images|grep telegraf
telegraf                                                                  <none>      4fffb7e68242   4 weeks ago     472MB

docker inspect 4fffb7e68242 --format='{{json .}}'| jq '"\(.Created) \(.Config.Env[1]) \(.RepoDigests)"'
"2024-08-12T15:27:35Z TELEGRAF_VERSION=1.31.3 [\"telegraf@sha256:848201b0601513122f567a6b690b5ef84abbb38e78ca461d1c1d3d7465691d39\"]"

I wonder what I am missing here. I'd appreciate any hint.
Edit;
The only thing I forgot to mention telegraf container run by a docker swarm stack. I think that would make a difference how images are pulled.

You are comparing an old pin of an image to the rebuild with a new base image:
$ regctl image digest telegraf:1.31
sha256:6b0d623c54754958fed356d2af239de21dcf7c95d63b76298d0cd70df79cc719

Comparing the old pin:
$ docker buildx imagetools inspect telegraf@sha256:05cbea951c5cf9da6c663321b32848c1b6ffdfa877563237838efa21b508b079
Name:      docker.io/library/telegraf@sha256:05cbea951c5cf9da6c663321b32848c1b6ffdfa877563237838efa21b508b079
MediaType: application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json
Digest:    sha256:05cbea951c5cf9da6c663321b32848c1b6ffdfa877563237838efa21b508b079

Manifests:
  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf@sha256:848201b0601513122f567a6b690b5ef84abbb38e78ca461d1c1d3d7465691d39
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    linux/amd64
  Annotations:
    org.opencontainers.image.url:             https://hub.docker.com/_/telegraf
    org.opencontainers.image.version:         1.31
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: amd64
    org.opencontainers.image.base.digest:     sha256:66e568a0a9e5131643f75cea2fe66c8b45cc0395469455b5769ec2f051ee687b
    org.opencontainers.image.base.name:       buildpack-deps:bookworm-curl
    org.opencontainers.image.created:         2024-09-05T00:09:53Z
    org.opencontainers.image.revision:        426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f
    org.opencontainers.image.source:          https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker.git#426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f:telegraf/1.31

  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf@sha256:2a62640c6c53a3deea2ef3848d66f2e39ff8674da9e55d8b4114f7ddc9a1b3bb
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    unknown/unknown
  Annotations:
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: amd64
    vnd.docker.reference.digest:              sha256:848201b0601513122f567a6b690b5ef84abbb38e78ca461d1c1d3d7465691d39
    vnd.docker.reference.type:                attestation-manifest

  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf@sha256:8ab2fcde5e8d5ae97676fa951049c91135adc065a30e0cd4dae5daef50665e42
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    linux/arm/v7
  Annotations:
    org.opencontainers.image.base.digest:     sha256:8ac69ca67724de8c39cb2e7713440ce46aca8326fccccd92d854145a4c486a36
    org.opencontainers.image.base.name:       buildpack-deps:bookworm-curl
    org.opencontainers.image.created:         2024-08-14T00:31:20Z
    org.opencontainers.image.revision:        426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f
    org.opencontainers.image.source:          https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker.git#426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f:telegraf/1.31
    org.opencontainers.image.url:             https://hub.docker.com/_/telegraf
    org.opencontainers.image.version:         1.31
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: arm32v7

  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf@sha256:2a1644b24ec3f214b33e4388d95ad4bf1e482a071ec24b625acd7d975f26d6c9
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    unknown/unknown
  Annotations:
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: arm32v7
    vnd.docker.reference.digest:              sha256:8ab2fcde5e8d5ae97676fa951049c91135adc065a30e0cd4dae5daef50665e42
    vnd.docker.reference.type:                attestation-manifest

  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf@sha256:7303af7d29d74d38605bfc94fd62d936ea8d42fed1515695e94d189a98c3537d
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    linux/arm64/v8
  Annotations:
    org.opencontainers.image.revision:        426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f
    org.opencontainers.image.source:          https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker.git#426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f:telegraf/1.31
    org.opencontainers.image.url:             https://hub.docker.com/_/telegraf
    org.opencontainers.image.version:         1.31
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: arm64v8
    org.opencontainers.image.base.digest:     sha256:8b5f3df20dc4d7dd3c5e730a8353ffa21a6ccb9d444507ebcc302cc3eaf6f3cf
    org.opencontainers.image.base.name:       buildpack-deps:bookworm-curl
    org.opencontainers.image.created:         2024-08-13T19:51:17Z

  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf@sha256:14a0be6cc37a23c99d9488415fa573f12dd555eb3a567a347fb4e89f6f91f819
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    unknown/unknown
  Annotations:
    vnd.docker.reference.digest:              sha256:7303af7d29d74d38605bfc94fd62d936ea8d42fed1515695e94d189a98c3537d
    vnd.docker.reference.type:                attestation-manifest
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: arm64v8

To the new tagged image:
$ docker buildx imagetools inspect telegraf:1.31
Name:      docker.io/library/telegraf:1.31
MediaType: application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json
Digest:    sha256:6b0d623c54754958fed356d2af239de21dcf7c95d63b76298d0cd70df79cc719

Manifests:
  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf:1.31@sha256:848201b0601513122f567a6b690b5ef84abbb38e78ca461d1c1d3d7465691d39
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    linux/amd64
  Annotations:
    org.opencontainers.image.source:          https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker.git#426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f:telegraf/1.31
    org.opencontainers.image.url:             https://hub.docker.com/_/telegraf
    org.opencontainers.image.version:         1.31
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: amd64
    org.opencontainers.image.base.digest:     sha256:66e568a0a9e5131643f75cea2fe66c8b45cc0395469455b5769ec2f051ee687b
    org.opencontainers.image.base.name:       buildpack-deps:bookworm-curl
    org.opencontainers.image.created:         2024-09-05T00:09:53Z
    org.opencontainers.image.revision:        426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f

  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf:1.31@sha256:2a62640c6c53a3deea2ef3848d66f2e39ff8674da9e55d8b4114f7ddc9a1b3bb
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    unknown/unknown
  Annotations:
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: amd64
    vnd.docker.reference.digest:              sha256:848201b0601513122f567a6b690b5ef84abbb38e78ca461d1c1d3d7465691d39
    vnd.docker.reference.type:                attestation-manifest

  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf:1.31@sha256:18ee367acddef6bc891ae4edf18785ecf75d7ce476c9c559baa36d06e58a27a1
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    linux/arm/v7
  Annotations:
    org.opencontainers.image.base.digest:     sha256:5f2f9b35615c65ef5907c414739f3c797f3ffed0d930f9dd7b804fb44c6e2f8a
    org.opencontainers.image.base.name:       buildpack-deps:bookworm-curl
    org.opencontainers.image.created:         2024-09-06T04:14:41Z
    org.opencontainers.image.revision:        426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f
    org.opencontainers.image.source:          https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker.git#426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f:telegraf/1.31
    org.opencontainers.image.url:             https://hub.docker.com/_/telegraf
    org.opencontainers.image.version:         1.31
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: arm32v7

  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf:1.31@sha256:06658911b19998c722152953ae140cd59e9be6fd7d10efce48dc0be4c7549c20
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    unknown/unknown
  Annotations:
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: arm32v7
    vnd.docker.reference.digest:              sha256:18ee367acddef6bc891ae4edf18785ecf75d7ce476c9c559baa36d06e58a27a1
    vnd.docker.reference.type:                attestation-manifest

  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf:1.31@sha256:8ab8223cf42035683913aac257a4a0bef2da657b9a1f9b6b82a25230789fe10f
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    linux/arm64/v8
  Annotations:
    org.opencontainers.image.base.name:       buildpack-deps:bookworm-curl
    org.opencontainers.image.created:         2024-09-05T20:30:15Z
    org.opencontainers.image.revision:        426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f
    org.opencontainers.image.source:          https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker.git#426ed76c51f465daebb33547e3bb9632b974440f:telegraf/1.31
    org.opencontainers.image.url:             https://hub.docker.com/_/telegraf
    org.opencontainers.image.version:         1.31
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: arm64v8
    org.opencontainers.image.base.digest:     sha256:3ecd6e86b392efaaa7b0ccfc022e224fe6542a1c5a76865b63fbe3362af4e489

  Name:        docker.io/library/telegraf:1.31@sha256:c3bffc37d556833052d636c8f9bf84c7db5f8a05ed0fe726ad051efba5fa8c3f
  MediaType:   application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json
  Platform:    unknown/unknown
  Annotations:
    com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch: arm64v8
    vnd.docker.reference.digest:              sha256:8ab8223cf42035683913aac257a4a0bef2da657b9a1f9b6b82a25230789fe10f
    vnd.docker.reference.type:                attestation-manifest

It looks like the ARM base images were updated, while the AMD64 base image is unchanged and the image was reproducibly built to the same digest.

What I found puzzling is if I pull 1.31 and also pull 05cbea9 on top of it, I see both digests but now I understand how it works. Thanks for taking time and helping me out. I highly appreciate it.
